# how to copy some old harddrives onto an imac

Tags: hard-drive, imac

I have some old hard drives from my former linux box (RedHat).  Alas, that computer is dead, though the hard drives as far as I know are still viable.  I now have an iMac and I would like to retrieve the files from the old hard drive.  Does anyone know how to do that?

Basically, what I have is an iMac and 3 old hard drives.

Comment: Why the negative?  Was this a duplicate?  I looked to find whether this was a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy actually. You can buy hard drive enclosures that allow you to use a normal hard drive as an external disk.

See, [for example amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_13?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=hard%20drive%20enclosure&sprefix=hard%20drive%20en,aps,181).

Answer (score 1):

What interface on the old drives? There are several options to connect via USB.  This will connect SATA drives.  [Startech dual drive Dock](http://ca.startech.com/HDD/Docking/eSATA-USB-to-SATA-Hard-Drive-Docking-Station-for-Dual-25-or-35in-HDD~SATADOCK22UE)  There are others with USB3 and eSATA.  Also this cable type solution that does IDE and SATA[Startech USB IDE/Sata cable](http://ca.startech.com/HDD/Adapters/USB-20-to-IDE-or-SATA-Adapter-Cable~USB2SATAIDE)  Many manufacturers other than Startech

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an enclosure to house the drives, you should be able to mount them on your Mac using MacFUSE [discussions.apple.com has a how-to](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4043564?start=0&tstart=0)

If you want to be extra-careful and work with a copy, the command-line utility [dd](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/dd-command-examples/) can be used to make a byte-for-byte copy of each drive, and you could then mount the copy.